# Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x)=0$ if $x$ rational and if $x$ is irrational , then $f(x)=9^n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x)=0$ if $x$ rational and if $x$ is irrational , then $f(x)=9^n$ , where $n$ is the number of zeros immediately after the deciam point in the decimal representation of $x$ . Then the Lebesgure integral $\int ^1_0f(x)dx$ equals

i really have no idea about this question where to start...

Comment: How can $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is rational and equal something that isn't $0$ if $x$ is ration.  Do you mean $f(x) = 9^n$ if $x$ is *ir*rational?

Comment: @fleablood..sorry i was edited now ..thank you for correcting me

Comment: We can ignore the values of where $x$ is rational as the rationals have measure zero.  $f(.1-1) = 1$ and $f(.01-.1)=9$ etc.  So it makes sense that $\int_{0}^1 f(x) dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 9^n*\frac 9{10^{n+1} }= \sum (\frac 9{10})^{n+1}= 1$.  Now... we just need to justify it with acceptably sophisticated math rather than hand-waving common sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Another way of writing $f(x)$ is

$f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is rational.

if $10^{-n-1} \le x < 10^{-n}$ and if $x$ is irrational, then $f(x) = 9^n$

So $\int_{10^{-n-1}}^{10^{-n}}f(x)dx = [10^{-n}-10^{-n-1}]*9^n - measure\{q \in \mathbb Q|10^{-n-1} \le q < 10^{-n}\}*9^n= $

$[10^{-n}-10^{-n-1}]*9^n= 10^{-n-1}[10 -1]*9^n = \frac {9^{n+1}}{10^{n+1}} = (\frac 9{10})^{n+1}$.

So $\int_{0}^1f(x) dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac 9{10})^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac 9{10})^n -1=$

$\frac 1{1-\frac 9{10}} - 1 = 10 - 1 = 9$.

Comment: @fleablood...thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The set $\{x: f(x) > 0\}$ has measure $0$.

Comment: Not if $f(x) = 9^n$ for $x$ *irrational*.  Which admittedly was not the original post.  But the original post was contradictory and did not indicted *anything* about the values of $f(x)$ if $x$ was irrational.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom..........thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Define 
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 9^n 1_{[\frac{1}{10^n}, \frac{1}{10^{n-1}})} (x)$$

Then $f(x)=g(x)$ almost everywhere.

Comment: @N.S.........thank you so much